# ARMv8 NEON vector permute

Tags: assembly, arm, simd, neon, armv8

Consider memory laid out such that eight consecutive 4-byte blocks read `[abcdefgh]`. I load these into two registers `v0.4s` and `v1.4s`, so I get `v0.4s = [abcd]` and `v1.4s = [efgh]`, where each character represents a 32-bit block. I want to reorder them to obtain `[abef]` and `[cdgh]` in two (possibly different) registers.

My approach at the moment would be to first reverse the 64-bit halves of `[efgh]` to get `[ghef]`. Then I can use extract to get `[abef]` and `[ghcd]`. I can then again finally reverse the 64-bit halves of `[ghcd]` to get `[cdgh]`.

Can anyone tell a better approach?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `zip`, `uzp` or `trn`?

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what the TRN instructions are meant for:

//    v0: abcd
//    v1: efgh

```
trn1 v2.2d, v0.2d, v1.2d
trn2 v3.2d, v0.2d, v1.2d
```

//    v2: abef
//    v3: cdgh

And please please, don't ask me why it's 2d and not 4s.